# Get points of svg/xaml arc

Tags: xaml, math, svg, geometry, geometric-arc

Format of svg arc (arc in xaml have same args):

```
(rx ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag sweep-flag x y)
```

Description:

> Draws an elliptical arc from the current point to (x, y). The size and orientation of the ellipse are defined by two radii (rx, ry) and an x-axis-rotation, which indicates how the ellipse as a whole is rotated relative to the current coordinate system. The center (cx, cy) of the ellipse is calculated automatically to satisfy the constraints imposed by the other parameters. large-arc-flag and sweep-flag contribute to the automatic calculations and help determine how the arc is drawn.

I need to calc all point of it arc (with some step, of course). How I can do it? I would like to code on C# or on Java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bresenham algorithm is invented for point-by-point drawing.

Some code found for rotated ellipse ([wayback machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20110217051544/http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/awf/graphics/bres-ellipse.html))

Added:
How to transform zero-centered ellipse to needed implicit form (A,B,C,D,E,F)

```
A := (Cos(fi)/rx)^2 + (Sin(fi)/ry)^2;

C := (Sin(fi)/rx)^2 + (Cos(fi)/ry)^2;

B := Sin(2*fi)*(1/(ry*ry) - 1/(rx*rx));

D=E=0;

F:=-1
```

Checked for rx=100, ry=60, fi=Pi/6:
[image]

One more step: Delphi function to obtain implicit form for an **arbitrary** ellipse.
I hope that code is understandable (Sqr(x) = x*x)

```
//calc implicit ellipse equation
//semiaxes rx, ry; rotated at fi radians; centered at (cx,cy)
//x = rx * Cos(t) * Cos(fi) - ry * Sin(t) * Sin(fi) + cx
//y = rx * Cos(t) * Sin(fi) + ry * Sin(t) * Cos(fi) + cy
//To obtain implicit equation, exclude t
//note: implicit form Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+F=0 (not 2B,2D,2E)

procedure CalcImplicitEllipseEquation(rx, ry, fi, cx, cy: Double;
                                      var A, B, C, D, E, F:  Double);
begin
  B := Sin(2 * Fi) * (ry * ry - rx * rx);
  A := Sqr(ry * Cos(fi)) + Sqr(rx * Sin(fi));
  C := Sqr(rx * Cos(fi)) + Sqr(ry * Sin(fi));
  D := -B * cy - 2 * A * cx;
  E := -2 * C * cy - B * cx;
  F := C * cy * cy + A * cx * cx + B * cx * cy - rx * rx * ry * ry;
end;
```

Comment: But how transform (rx ry x-axis-rotation large-arc-flag sweep-flag x y) to (A B C D E F)?